# QT and OpenCV error: core.hpp not found

Tags: qt, opencv, linker, qmake, include-path

i have installed qt 5.0.2 with opencv 2.4.5 with windows 7 32-bit following this [tutorial](http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml) but when i finished i tested it using the example mentioned in the previous link but i had this error

```
error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

### Update

---

top 5 errors:

```
C:\opencv\opencv_bin\install\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp:4341: In file included from ..\..\..\..\..\..\opencv\opencv_bin\install\include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4341:0,
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test2\main.cpp:2: from ..\test2\main.cpp:2:
C:\opencv\opencv_bin\install\include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp:928: error: prototype for 'cv::Vec<_Tp, n> cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>::solve(const cv::Vec<_Tp, m>&, int) const' does not match any in class 'cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>'
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\test2\main.cpp:2: In file included from ..\test2\main.cpp:2:0:
C:\opencv\opencv_bin\install\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp:495: error: candidates are: cv::Matx<_Tp, n, 1> cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>::solve(const cv::Matx<_Tp, m, 1>&, int) const
```

Could anybody help me please to determine what's the matter and how to
 solve it.

Comment: You forgot to pass search paths to OpenCV includes to the compiler.

Comment: so,, what is the solution?

Comment: The solution is to pass them... Are you completely new to software development?

Comment: this type of software development,,, yes

Comment: These errors are actually really bad ones because they come from OpenCV source code. It feels like something is wrong with your installation.

Comment: I can still see that you didn't show me errors properly. You omitted them. For instance, the first one ends `.../core.hpp:4341:0,`, but after this comma there should be more related to this one, and you've stripped it.

Comment: it has been solved,, thank u see the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved... it was copmatability issues between the q creator and opencv,,, i've installed [QTsdK](http://www.ulozto.net/xme6ZLb/qtsdk-offline-win-x86-v1-2-1-exe)  , [opencv 2.3.1](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and [cmake 2.8.11](http://cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) follwing the same [tutorial](http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml)   and every think goes in the right way :)

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial, this guy actually tells you how to do that. Extract:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = myFirstOpenCVProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OpenCV-2.3.1\\install\\include # <--- this
LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV-2.3.1\\install\\lib \
    -lopencv_core231.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui231.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc231.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d231.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d231.dll
```

Comment: the previous error disappeared but i  got 79 new errors,(my code is copy from the one in the tutorial)

Comment: 1) That gives me no information on how to help you. So you should definitely update your question by adding output of a few errors, so that I can see them. 2) I can already anticipate that these are linking errors. So I ask again, have you ever programmed in C++ seriously (labs in university do not count)? 3) Copying code without understanding what it does and how it should be built and deployed does not imply that it will work for you as it does for the author.

Comment: 1) i appreciate ur help,,, i already did i posted two errors 2)i also think it's linking error but i'm not able to fix it, of course i had c++ labs but with no linking problems 3)i programmed my whole project using opencv and c++ so don't u think i will not understand a simple program to read image and display it??. i'm just not familiar with qt it's the first time i used it i usually programmed c++ using visual studio

Comment: I'm not saying that you cannot understand the program, in fact, I'm sure you can. The problem I'm pointing out is that you're unfamiliar with how to incorporate 3rd party libraries (such as OpenCV) in your projects properly, i.e. how to perform linking and includes, which is pretty basic knowledge, and it has nothing to do with Qt in particular. It's rather the everyday routine, the one you should be comfortable with, and be able to solve on your own. Anyway, I understand that it can be troublesome due to lack of experience, so I'll help you out.

Comment: First of all, are the errors you've posted the first ones in the output? If not, then please post the very first ones, 4 - 5 would be enough.